# How to check if option value was selected? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-autocomplete, mat-option

I have a template, with mat-autocomplete, in which I search for elements and I have `option` elements - each individual element. My goal is to write logic: if I have an element selected, my input should be disabled. How can I check whether a certain element was selected in mat-autocomplete?

HTML

```
<input [matAutocomplete]="auto" matInput formControlName="targetListValue">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let targetItem of filteredTargetListOptions" [value]="targetItem">
     {{targetItem.value}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Typescript

```
ifSelectedItem() {
 if (// if option has been selected) {
   this.form.controls.targetListValue.disable();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs (https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) MatAutoComplete has a `optionSelected` output. Hence I'd try the following:

```
<input [matAutocomplete]="auto" matInput formControlName="targetListValue">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="ifSelectedItem()">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let targetItem of filteredTargetListOptions" [value]="targetItem">
     {{targetItem.value}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript

```
isOptionSelected(event: any) {
   const selectedValue = event.option.value
   if (selectedValue) {
     this.form.controls.targetListValue.disable();
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="isOptionSelected($event)" 
                  [displayWith]="displayFn"
                  #auto="matAutocomplete"
>
    // options
</mat-autocomplete>
```